# Write error saving DB on disk(rdbSaveRio): Function not implemented

Tags: windows, ubuntu, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

im encourtering "Write error saving DB on disk(rdbSaveRio): Function not implemented" on my redis server and is running on Windows Subsystem for Linux - Ubuntu, Windows Server 2019 Data Center version 1809.

How to fix the problem. i have been looking for a solution and cant find one.